# How to set Image path in Python

Tags: python

I have the below python code that selects all the images in the same directory of the python file and hashes them in order to receive a hash txt file.
I would prefer to set only the needed image and not to hash all the images.
can you please advise how and where can I set the name of the image or the path? (ex: to hash only the following image C:\Users\admin\Desktop\TD\image.png)

THE CODE is the below :

```
import os
import hashlib
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='InitializationHash.txt', level=logging.INFO,
                    format='%(message)s')

image_ext = ['.png', '.jpg']

def hash_image(filepath):
    with open(filepath, 'rb') as f:
        file_bytes = f.read()
        hash_text = hashlib.sha256(file_bytes).hexdigest()
        logging.info(hash_text)

def get_images(path):
    for f in os.listdir(path):
        full_path = os.path.join(path, f)
        if os.path.isdir(full_path):
            get_images(full_path)
        else:
            ext = os.path.splitext(full_path)[1]
            if ext in image_ext:
                hash_image(full_path)
if __name__ == '__main__':
   get_images(".")
```

Comment: you add like 'and' condition to the line `if os.path.isdir(full_path):` to check if the path mentioned contains any substring of your interest or not, so the modified code would be like `if os.path.isdir(fullpath) and 'image' in fullpath` , in this example, image is your substring of your interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to pass in the name of a file and only hash that one file you can create a new function like this

```
def get_one_image(file_Name):
    filepath = os.path.abspath(file_Name)
    hash_image(filepath)
```

you can call that instead

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   get_one_image("FileName.png")
```